# How are absolute diamond grid positions calculated?

Tags: css

So there are many tutorials that show you how to create diamond grids but the only thing that really confuses me is how they calculate the positions.

For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpphbq55/

So how do I find out what values to use for the margins? I mean if I were to change the size it would take me a lot of experimenting to get the right value for the negative margins.

Here a snippet from the jsfiddle. The css is from a tutorial:

```
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 66px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.diamond-grid {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 10px;
}ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 66px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.diamond {
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.diamond-grid > li:nth-child(9n+6) {
    margin-left: 66px;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
.diamond-grid > li:nth-child(5) {
    margin-left: 182px;
}
.diamond-grid > li:nth-child(n+5) {
    margin-top: -51px;
}
```

Comment: Use [trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry)

Comment: @Oriol maybe you can show an example in css. As far as im concerned css only supports a calc function. Math.sin or Math.cos functions are not available.

Comment: Yes, CSS won't calculate the values for you, but you can use a calculator.

Comment: @Oriol I wasnt aware that you use trigonometry for that. I know the basic concept but im not sure where to start with the calculation.